# PHP Session Variable Passing

Tags: php, session, variables

I can't seem to see why the `$_SESSION['email']` isn't being passed

#### Page 1 Segment

```
<?php
if (isset($finalusername, $finalpass, $finalemail)) {
$myFile = "users/$finalusername.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("There was an error in creating your account.  <br />");
$stringData = "$finalusername\n";
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
$stringData = "$finalpass\n";
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
$stringData = "$finalemail\n";
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
fclose($fh);

// set session variable
session_start();
$_SESSION['email'] = "$finalemail";

echo "<a href='emailverify.php'><button>Continue to Email Verification Page</button></a>";
}
?>
```

#### Page 2 Segment

```
<?php

// Check if your session variable is active
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['email'])) {

$message = rand(111111111, 999999999);
$to = "email@email.com";
$subject = "Test mail";
$from = "email@email.com";
$headers = "From:" . $from;
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
session_start();
unset($_SESSION['email']);
}
?>
```

I really cant see what i've done wrong. I know everything else is eprfect because the rest of the code works.

Comment: `session_start()` should be always placed on the top of PHP script

Comment: call `session_start()` always at the very beginning (just to be sure). Also the second call to `session_start()` in the page 2 script isn't neccessary.

Comment: Yupp, @MarekSebera, that's it. Also, no multiple calls will help.

Comment: Wow...is that really all? lol That was really simple goodness im a noob :( Thanks everyone though!

Comment: How come session_start() should be placed on top? 100% wrong , he isnt sending anything to the browser unless fopen didnt work or errors appear. Also you can use ob_start() and you can place session_start() anywhere you want. I don't see anything that will be sent to the browser b4 session_start() in that script.

Comment: So my guess would be maybe you get an error or fopen didnt work . Try setting the error_reporting to E_ALL. If the code b4 session_start in page1 runs smoothly then maybe your session cookie is somehow removed between pages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"`session_start()` is used in PHP to initiate a session on each PHP page. It must be the first thing sent to the browser, or it won't work properly, so it's usually best to place it right after the `<?php` tag. This must be on every page you intend to use sessions on."

http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php